# vs2012 Adding TransientFaultHandling 6.0 dll fails

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reference, enterprise-library-6

When I right click VS References and goto Manage NuGet, I type in and search "enterprise library -" and then tried to add TransientFaultHandling - but it fails. I also tried adding the Logging Application block and that installed ok.
Any ideas how to fix this or what's wrong?

I'm using the starter Hands on Lab sample from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40286
 Once that's extracted, the path to the solution files is at: \Transient Fault Handling\exercises\Lab01\begin\TransientFaultHandlingHOL\

Here's the error message I get

Successfully installed 'EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling 6.0.1304.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling 6.0.1304.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling 6.0.1304.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but **the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework**. For more information, contact the package author.

I also tried installing TransientFaultHandling when my c# project targeted .net 4.0 and the same message occurs.

Comment: What version of NuGet are you using?  Looks like there is a [Known Issue](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib6ReleaseNotes#KnownIssues) with requiring NuGet 2.2 (or higher).  Perhaps this is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Visual Studio and NuGet Manager.

In Visual Studio, click Tools and then Extension Manager. Click on the Updates tab to check for updates.

It worked for me...